# How to handle Spring Bean initializing exception when application startup and How to display/redirect custom 500 error.jsp

Tags: spring, servlets

I have a Spring Bean class(Test) which is registered as bean in applicationContext.xml file. This bean is loading during the application startup itself, it contains application initialization stuff. But while loading application one of the bean class method giving exception. I need to handle this error/exception case and need to show as 500 custom error.jsp page.

Sample code snippet :

```
class TestBean {
    public TestBean(){
        doStuff() ;
    }

    public void doStuff() {
    try {
        //some business logic
    } catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error("error message"); //here i am just logging the error message
    }
    }
 }
```

I have tried in different scenarios like below :

1) Throwing custom exception with 500 as the error code.

```
 class TestBean {
    public TestBean() throws CustomCheckedException{
        doStuff() ;
    }

    public void doStuff() throws CustomCheckedException{
    try {
        some logic
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new CustomCheckedException(500,"errorMessage");
    }
    }
 }


public class CustomCheckedException extends Exception {

    public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomCheckedException.class.getName());

    String errorMessage;

    int errorCode;

    public CustomCheckedException(int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
        super();
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
        this.errorCode = errorCode;

    }

    public CustomCheckedException() {

    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public int getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public void setErrorCode(int errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }
```

web.xml code :

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

error.jsp page is located in webapp folder

2) Not throwing any custom exception just giving specific exception in web.xml like below.

```
    <error-page>
 <exception-type>java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException</exception-type>
        <location>/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

But i am not able to display the custom error.jsp page when the exception occured during application initialization.
I have seen some other way also like :
res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "error message");
but in my bean class i dont have the response object. If i try to Autowire HttpServletResponse into my bean class still i am getting response object as null only.

Can any one tell me where i am doing wrong and which approach is good for displaying custom error page if any exception occurs during application startup.

Answer (score 0):

Define the one global exception handler using Spring AOP by using @ExceptionHandler
annotion from which you can send the ModelView which contain name of your Error JSP page which is render by resolver.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Controller
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {


@ExceptionHandler(value = { CustomCheckedException.class })
public ModelView
 handleCustomCheckedException(CustomCheckedException customCheckedException, 
 HttpServletRequest request) {

 return //your model view ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the answer.Tried in that way but not working. As of my knowledge i think @ControllerAdvice apply globally to all Controllers but in my case it is still in application loading stage not even reached to any controller.

Answer (score 0):

As of my search in google i understood that we can not redirect error.jsp file if any exceptions occuring during bean initialization time. 
What i did for this is instead of throwing the custom exception(throw new CustomCheckedException(500,"errorMessage")), i am handling that exception in catch and making the bean initialization properly(by providing required parameter values with some false values when exception occurs) and making application to run.

For error.jsp i am handling in the filters:
Created one filter by extending GenericFilterBean class and getting the bean class object using WebApplicationContext and checking the variables values of the bean class.
If the variable values are false values then i am redirecting to error page(response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).

```
public class CustomBeanFilter  extends GenericFilterBean implements Filter{
    SampleBean bean;
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
   throws IOException, ServletException {
  HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
  if (bean.falseValue) {
        res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
 }

 public void destroy() {
 }

 @Override
 public void initFilterBean() throws ServletException {
     WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext =
             WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
         //reference to bean from app context
         this.bean = webApplicationContext.getBean(SampleBean.class);
 }
}
```

Configured error-code as 500 in web.xml

```
<error-page> 
     <error-code>500</error-code>
     <location>/error.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
```

So when there is any exception in my bean class then it is redirecting to the error page(error.jsp)